# Input field with predefined value

Tags: html, input

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve an input field with a fixed first-value that handles the following requirements:

1. Doesn't use the  element as it's already taken.
2. Works with values of any width.

Example: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDjHX.jpg]

Thanks

Comment: I guess you talk about html elements, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @ChristianGärtner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve that using Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq65g/

In this, I have created 2 input boxes:

- First for taking user input, and is visible
- Second for storing the actual value, and is invisible

The first passes value to the second.

### HTML

```
<div class="input">
<div class="preval">
<span>http://</span>
</div>
<div class="text">
<input type="text" onchange="process(this)">
<input type="url" id="data" name="data" style="display:none;">
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.input {
    display: table;
    height: 45px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #3bc;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.input *{
    position: relative;
}
div.input div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
div.input div.preval {
    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: default;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3bc;
}
div.input div.text {
    padding: 10px;
}
div.input input {
    appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0;
}
div.input input:focus {
    outline: #C3E8EC solid 2px;
    outline-offset: 8px;
}
```

### Javascript

```
function process(elem) {
    if (elem.value!="") {
        document.getElementById('data').value = "http://"+elem.value;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('data').value = "";
    }
}
```